# Development & Production Ports

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, vue.js

I have an issue with my deployed app 'https://dova.vercel.app'.

In dev mode the base_url is 'http://localhost:8081'

Must I also specify the port in prod mode like so 'https://dova.vercel.app:8081'

Coz currently it's only 'https://dova.vercel.app'.

**THE THING IS, IN DEVELOPMENT THE BASE_URL [TOGETHER WITH ITS PORT] COMMUNICATES WITH MY MONGO ATLAS DB
BUT IN PRODUCTION THE BASE_URL [WITHOUT PORT SPECIFIED] DOESN'T SEEM TO COMMUNICATE WITH MY DB**

Comment: Default port for HTTP is 80 and for HTTPS it is 443, so https://dova.vercel.app is really https://dova.vercel.app:443, also take note, on your site you try to connect to "localhost", maybe thats the problem (a typo)?

Comment: Hie boss, pliz visit this public git repo 'https://github.com/Yacie/dova-poems' for my minified app and help me debug. This version is hosted at https://dova-poems.vercel.app. Wud appreciate if you also upload yo working copy to https://vercel.com so that we are on the same environment

Comment: Sorry but I dont have time for that.